# Word macro to create telephone list from active directory

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office

Is there a macro or little appliaction that allows our secretary to print a new phone list, but the data should come from active directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script pulls all the [users](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/m_29830/tm.htm) into Excel with full information
[This one](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/csc/scripts/ad/users/cscad057.mspx) just pulls the basics but is a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward once you have the LDAP query you need to pull the information from Active Directory.  See a guide which will get you started [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(EXCHG.65).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Theres a good article on how to do so with a batch file [here](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/79452/jsi-tip-7340-how-can-i-create-a-telephone-directory-from-my-active-directory-domain.html). You can use this to output to a text file that could then be edited in word.

If you want something more advanced there are a number of perl scripts out there that will do it.